# How to create a RESTful api which responds at a later time.

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, delay

is it possible to create a RESTful API in Java which receives a request from client say mobile/web app, the client drops the connection and checks back after say 5 or 10 minutes for the response of it's earlier request. Is it doable? If yes, could you please provide me some pointers to start with. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you cannot do that. However the client which consumes the API service could notice if the connection dropped and save the request which could not be resolved.... Then when the connection comes back, do the request again. The server (API) doesn't need to know about its client's connection status.

Comment: Yes, it's doable. Response to original request is a unique identifier representing the request, e.g. a "RequestId". Follow-up call then asks for status of that request, by id, and if request is complete, can get the full response. You'd likely want to store request in a database, so it persists if server is restarted.

Comment: you can also approach like a batch job submission and another api to check and retrieve status

Comment: @Andreas Thank you. I cannot select your response as answer so up-voting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what happens when the client drops. Does the client receive anything back?

If so, you can just return some sort of unique ID and the client can send a request with the unique ID to check its status.

Comment: Question is not asking for server to initiate communication when request is complete. It specifically states that client will "check back after say 5 or 10 minutes". Your answer is to suggest what the question is already intending to do. Not useful.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. My reading comprehension is definitely off today. Will update, as part of the answer is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is also called long polling.
Maybe this can help
https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/14/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application